# await function inside third-party non-async function

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

```
async function myAsyncFunc() : Promise<void> {
    // do async stuff
    // ex. delay with promise of setTimout
}

libraryObject.onBeforeDrawOnScreen(function(){
    myAsyncFunc(); // can't "await" or block.
});
```

How can I wait before exit from 'onBeforeDrawOnScreen'?

The library doesn't care about the callback's return type or value. There is no spacial check for Promise return, So it doesnt 'await' on my callack.
so I cant add 'async' word on the callback.

I'm aware to javascript's event loop, but ... There is a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be if `libraryObject` provides some cancelling mechanism for `"draw-on-screen"` events.

Comment: No, this is impossible. File a bug report with the library for featuring asynchrony, or choose a different third party.

Answer (score 0):

I'd see if you can find a better library, or-- if the library you're using is open-source-- try contributing async support yourself. Otherwise, there really isn't any way to do this.

It might occur to you to do what's called a busy-wait, where you have a while loop that repeatedly checks some state that will be changed by a resolving promise. Even this won't work, though, because of the single-threaded nature of JS. The very handlers responsible for getting you out of the loop are blocked until you get out of the loop. **Note: the following will cause an infinite loop, so don't actually do it**:

```
libraryObject.onBeforeDrawOnScreen(function(){
    let done = false;
    let error = null;
    myAsyncFunc()
        .then(() => {
            done = true;
        }, (err) => {
            error = err;
            done = true;
        });
    while(!done);
    if (error) throw error;
});
```

This is why async support is so crucial in many JS libraries.

Comment: All your three reasons why this is a bad idea are secondary. You should not do it - can not do it - because it simply doesn't work. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Right you are. The promise handlers that set the `done` variables are never called because they can't be until the function exits. I probably should have tried it before posting it. >.<